# Process Azure Analysis sevice via SSIS. Error: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: ssis, azure-analysis-services

I hope you are well..
I really need your help to help me resolve an issue.

I created an SSIS package (SSIS 2012) which processes a tabular model in Azure AS.
To do this I created a task script (C # 2010) and I had to add 2 references Microsoft.AnalysisService.Core and Microsoft.AnalysisService.Tabular.

The package runs fine when I run it locally.

However when I deploy it on the SSIS server and run it I get this error: "Error: Unable to connect to the remote server".

Do you know where this error could come from?
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Hello All.    Any idea ??

Comment: Hello all, Any idea ?